# What is the minimum interface that has the Count property in .Net

Tags: .net, arrays, inheritance, collections, list

I need to change a method that has one parameter that takes a serie of objects. I need to find the lowest Interface (in inheritance tree) that has the Count property. Until now I was using the IEnumerable but as this has not Count I need to change it to the wider interface possible so the method can work with the biggest number of types of series (collections, lists, arrays, etc).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ICollection` adds the `Count` property.

As @Joren rightly points point, `IEnumerable<T>` has the extension method `Count<T>()` if you're happy making your collection generic. However, as @Joel Coehoorn has pointed out, it is inadvisable to use this as it forces an iteration of the sequence.

Comment: That's the lowest at the Hierarchy tree?

Comment: The Count<T> method is an extension method on IEnumerable<T>, not a method on ICollection<T>. (ICollection<T> just has the Count property, which it inherits from ICollection.) Of course ICollection<T> inherits from IEnumerable<T>, so the extension method is valid on ICollection<T> instances. My point is that for the Count<T> method, IEnumerable<T> is more fundamental than ICollection<T>.

Comment: Yes, ICollection is what adds the Count property. Other things that have the property will generally be implementing ICollection (IList, IDictionary etc.).

Comment: Don't use IEnumerable's .Count extension.  It forces an iteration of the sequence.

Answer (score 5):

[ICollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx) adds the Count property.

Answer (score 4):

[`System.Collections.ICollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icollection.aspx), and also [`System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx). These two interfaces have no relation to eachother, but both inherit from IEnumerable, so they're at the same level.

IEnumerable obviously does not have a Count property (the count isn't necessarily predetermined).